# Trying to System.out.print() in a setOnMouseClicked event [Java app]

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java application that calls a method `letsPlay`. I want to see if the code works, and sout'ed to test if it's running or not. When I run the app, nothing is printed. Is it because Java doesn't sout anything, or is it a problem with my code?

```
private void letsPlay(boolean player1turn) {
    if(player1playing && player1turn)       
        System.out.println("It is " + nameField1.getText() + "'s turn.");
}
```

Comment: Where is your definition of player1playing?

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's going on with the state of your variables while your code is running.

Comment: How are you calling `letsPlay` method and what's the value of player1playing variable? Just print those two variables before that if and see what the value is? Use IDE's to debug the code.

Answer (score 2):

One of the two:

- (probably) `player1playing` or/and `player1turn` are `false`, causing the expression to be evaluated to `false`, so the statement won't be executed
- output stream is directed to somewhere else and not to the console, to solve this you'll need to do something like:

  ```
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
  ```

The easiest way to find what's your problem is to *debug* your code. Use the debugger, it'll save for you time, much of it.